# Expire JS cookie every Saturday

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie, expired-cookies

I need to be able to set a cookie and have it expire every saturday using Javascript but not sure where to begin.

var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDay();

document.cookie =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to define next Saturday this way.

```
var nextSaturday = new Date();
nextSaturday.setDate(nextSaturday.getDate() + (6 + 7 - nextSaturday.getDay()) % 7);
```

if you `console.log(nextSaturday)` it will give you the date of next Saturday. Then you can store your cookie like this:

```
document.cookie = "myCookie=ok; expires=" + nextSaturday;
```

Comment: Glad to help you